# PHP encrypts a password with RSA decryption and Android sees some junk data plus the true data after decryption

Tags: php, android

I'm using RSA and AES encryption/Decryption
I create RSA public key and private key in Android
I send public key to PHP server

Utilizing AES encryption, PHP encrypts some large data with a password and utilizing RSA encyption and the received public key, it encodes the password and then returns back the encrypted large data with the password and the encoded encrypted password where the encode function is as following: 
`base64_encode(the encrypted password)`

In Android, I first decode the encoded encrypted password where the decode instruction is as following:`Base64.decode(the encoded encrypted password, Base64.DEFAULT)`

PHP code is as following:

```
openssl_public_encrypt($password, $encrypted, $public_key);
$mystr= base64_encode($encrypted);
echo "mystrStart=$mystr mystrEnd\n"; //mystr will be retrieved in Android
```

Android code is as following:

```
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] encryptedBytes,decryptedBytes;
encryptedBytes = Base64.decode(mystr, Base64.DEFAULT);
decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
String DecryptedPassword = new String(decryptedBytes);
```

The problem is I see the password at the end of DecryptedPassword but some other junk data before the password is yet seen:

The password in PHP is "Hellooooo"

mystr (the encoded encrypted password) received in Android is as following:

> sNfmwifoIEqXQzzge0zOFmBTFPlDqQZkAWqOPtGe3jNuI/zdV4SsCTxzcNZvww5RaaMOZ4ubQWrGXLuyuimKeQ==

The final result (DecryptedPassword) is as following:

> ����/
>                                                                                      +�*@7JY��,��7��$C�-|8�[��p��Ĭ���,9v��}��Hellooooo

edit:
The code is as following:

```
        KeyPairGenerator kpg;
        KeyPair kp;
        PublicKey publicKey;
        final PrivateKey privateKey;

        try {
            kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            kpg.initialize(512);
            kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
            publicKey = kp.getPublic();
            privateKey = kp.getPrivate();

            byte[] pKbytes = Base64.encode(publicKey.getEncoded(), 0);
            String pK = new String(pKbytes);
            String pubKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" + pK + "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";

            Log.e(TAG, "pubKey:"+pubKey);
```

And then this `pubKey` is saved to a file named U.txt and then sent to the server

```
SendJSONToServerTest someTask = new SendJSONToServerTest(getApplicationContext(), "FileName"+".txt", PHP_address, getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + "U.txt", new SendJSONToServerTest.OnEventListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String result) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "log1 = "+result);
                    String mstr = getBetweenStrings(result,"mystrStart=","mystrEnd");
                    Log.e(TAG, "log2 = "+mstr);

                    try {
                        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
                        byte[] encryptedBytes, decryptedBytes;
                        encryptedBytes = Base64.decode(mstr, Base64.DEFAULT);
                        decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);

                        String DecryptedPassword = new String(decryptedBytes);
                        Log.e(TAG, "log3= "+DecryptedPassword);

                     } catch(GeneralSecurityException e) {
                         System.out.println(e);
                     }
                     Log.e(TAG, "Endddddddddddddd");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(String f) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "errR.......");
                }
            });
            someTask.execute();
```

PHP code related to file content:

```
$fileContentStr = file_get_contents($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"]);
echo "\nfileContentStr = {$fileContentStr}\n";

$public_key = $fileContentStr;
echo "\npublic_key = {$public_key}\n";
```

Comment: `mystr (the encoded encrypted password) received in Android is as following:.`. Ok. But is it the same as is sent by php? Did you check that to begin with?

Comment: yes it's the same

Comment: I tested that with phpseclib too and when **setEncryptionMode** is set to **CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_OAEP**, Hellooooo is not seen in the log but when I change that to **CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1** the result is as following:7���>-B�ğ��$�d����~��*0�b4 �i ��Ҏ��̞cB����Hellooo which is similar to openssl

Comment: Please try do decode and decrypt all on php side for a test. What do you get? Try to do all on Android side too. Then compare step by step. What i miss in your story is sizes/lengths of used arrays and strings at all steps. Determine them and compare.

Comment: Further you could post complete code which we only have to copy/paste so we could test it out.

Comment: there is no sizes/lengths in the variables but the value 512 here: 
**KeyPairGenerator kpg;
KeyPair kp;
PublicKey publicKey;
final PrivateKey privateKey;
        
try {
       kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
       kpg.initialize(512);
       kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
       publicKey = kp.getPublic();
       privateKey = kp.getPrivate();

        byte[] pKbytes = Base64.encode(publicKey.getEncoded(), 0);
        String pK = new String(pKbytes);
        String pubKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" + pK + "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";**
...

Comment: and this is how I log: **Log.e(TAG, "the result is = "+DecryptedPassword);**

Comment: Please post code in your post. I will not read code in comments. Do you like to read code in comments?

Comment: The code is in the post

Comment: `And then this pubKey is saved to a file named U.txt and then sent to the server`. Why? Why dont you just send String pK to the server? And we cannot see php code that extracts the pK value. So how do we know that you do it right? You are not mentioning the used strings or string lengths.

Comment: I edited the post for PHP code but I verified the received public key by PHP code and the sent public key by Android and both were the same, but about your question on sending just String pk to the server please guide me more cause till now I've just communicated with the PHP code by uploading a file and not moving that file to the server if need be but I don't know how to do what you mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem and went searching and found the answer [here](https://kfalck.net/2011/03/07/decoding-pkcs1-padding-in-python/).

Basically, the message is padded and the byte just before your original method is the 0x00 byte (NUL character).

The following code was extracted from the link which removes the padding and returns the original message.

```
def pkcs1_unpad(text):
    if len(text) > 0 and text[0] == '\x02':
        # Find end of padding marked by nul
        pos = text.find('\x00')
        if pos > 0:
            return text[pos+1:]
    return None
```

I am decoding the encrypted message in python but it is easy to port it to PHP.

I hope this help you, too.

Comment: You mean "Hellooooo" is padded => let's name it "A", then encrypted => let's name it "B", then encoded => let's name it "C", then decoded in Android => let's name it "D", then decrypted with the private key => let's name it "E", now which one (A-E) is the argument of pkcs1_unpad function(text)?

Comment: “E”, the decrypted message, is the argument to pkcs1_unpad(text). E is text.  This means that if we consider the junk padding to be “J”, then E = J + A.

Comment: Applying the above to your message, we will find that the byte in the string just before the “H” in “Hellooooo” is in fact the nul character (\0 or 0x00)